# Public Domain Join Active Directory on Dedicated Server

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2016

**Server Environment**

- Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Standard (Desktop XP)
- Hosted: Dedicated Server
- NIC: 1 NIC with Static Public IP
- Roles: Active Directory Domain Services and DNS

**Client Environment**

- Operating System: Windows 10 x64
- Hosted: Dedicated Server
- NIC: 1 NIC with Static Public IP

**Network**

- Firewall: Not possible
- VLAN: Not possible
- VPN: Not possible

**Scenario**

Client has to join Active Directory Server. Server and Client has both one NIC with a Public IP. How can I do this without a VPN Server? It is possible to Join a DC from Public? How can I make it secure? Can I Whitelist the IP from the Clients on the Server to Join the DC?

Thanks for help

Comment: Given these restrictions it might actually be better to use Azure AD instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no firewall, VLAN and VPN are all not possible, then you have a huge security problem, possible solutions are:

1. Use a single host server that has Hyper-V enabled, run the DC and Windows 10 as VMs and let them speak over a dedicated virtual switch.
2. If you have to keep your environment as is, have whoever is responsible for the servers to connect them using a dedicated NIC internally, and harden the external NICs by disabling "Client for Microsoft networks", "File and printer sharing for Microsoft networks" and "NetBIOS on the TCP/IP".

Remember these are not the best solutions, and I will recommend hosting your AD at a secure network that is not exposed to the Internet, perhaps it's better to move to another hoster (assuming why you have so many limitations) or Azure Ad?